# Number of "positions" in a connector?

Tags: connector, pins

I have a part that says "2 positions", does this mean I could feed VCC through one pin and GND through the other, or are they 'connected'?

[image]

Source:[digikey.com](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&keywords=1757242)

Comment: They are not connected - use them as you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I use a similar connector and I feed Vcc into one of the pins and ground to the other.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already been answered but I just wanted to mention that "Positions" = "Pins". A 20-position connector means it has 20 separate pins.